# Angular Website Served Via Nginx on Amazon EC2 Returns 404

Tags: angularjs, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to serve an angular site on an ec2 instance using nginx.

In my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file I have defined a server:

```
server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

And in the http block, I have included the path to the config file like so:

```
include /home/bitnami/apps/mysite/mysite.conf;
```

The path is correct as the following terminal line opens the file in vim:

```
sudo vim /home/bitnami/apps/mysite/mysite.conf;
```

When I go to public.ip.address:8081, the Nginx welcome page shows. When I go to public.ip.address:9000 which should be mysite, I get a 404 error.

Other info:

- I'm using the MEAN Bitnami image on a 'tiny' ec2 instance. The free tier.
- Nginx starts and reloads fine
- I've added inbound rules for the security group on port 8080, 8081, and 9000. Port 8080 and port 8081 work, port 9000 does not.
- The exact same code works on my local machine, so I'm thinking it must be a permissions issue somewhere?

**EDIT**

- The working ports are 8080 and 8081. Port 8080 is my API for now. Port 8081 is the Nginx welcome page.

** THE PROBLEM **

The root in my mysite.conf was wrong.

```
server {
    listen 9000;
    root /Users/me/Repository/mysite/dist;

    access_log off;
    error_log off;

    index index.html;

    client_max_body_size 10m;

    location ^~ /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }

    location = /nginxstatus {
        access_log off;
        return 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are talking about three ports, 9000, 8000 and 8081, so which ports work?

Comment: 8081 and 8080, sorry, will clear that up. Port 8080 is actually my api for now.

Comment: But I didn't see any setting in nginx for port 9000.

Comment: @BMW - while typing that code, I found the error. My root was wrong in the mysite.conf. I'll add that info to the question and if you want to type up that answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: That's fine. The fix you pasted are different if compare with the original one.